# Implement requests with mapr

Tags: java

I have the following Java code snippet:

```
import org.ojai.Document;

public class JsonRepository {


    public Object jsonStore; // what type should be this Object 

    public Document createDocument()
    {
     ....
    }
}

import org.ojai.Document;
import org.ojai.DocumentStream;
import org.ojai.store.QueryCondition;

@Repository
public class accountRepository extends JsonRepository {

         public DocumentStream accountsAsStream(List<String> ids) {
              QueryCondition condition = jsonStore.getQueryCondition().in(123, ids);

              ......
              List<Document> documents = jsonStore.query(condition);
              .......

             return jsonStore.queryAsStream(condition);
         }

         public DocumentStream accountIdsAsStream() {
             return jsonStore.getAllDocumentsAsStream("id");
         }
}
```

I can't find what type of variable should be `jsonStore`. It needs to support these methods: `queryAsStream`, `query`, `queryAsStream`, `getAllDocumentsAsStream` etc. Do you know how I can find this?

PS. Test project: https://github.com/rcbandit111/ojai_poc

Comment: Is it possible to change the existing code?

Comment: Are you given the choice to update the old code?

Comment: I can update only the file class MainJsonRepository

Comment: Sure. I got the idea. will come up with the updated MainJsonRepository.

Comment: I saw the GitHub project that you provided and it's using `protected DocumentStore jsonStore;` and the last update was 5 days ago So could you please explain what you are trying to do and why you can't use DocumentStore? If you already resolved the issue please provide the solution as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code looks a bit out of date.

Could it be that you don't want to use the method `queryAsStream`, but would rather use `DocumentStore.find()`?

That returns a `QueryResult` which is a subclass of `DocumentStream`.

If this makes sense, then `jsonStore` should be of type `DocumentStore`.

See https://www.ojai.io/javadocs/latest/

Comment: I'm using `org.ojai:ojai:3.1.1`

Comment: Where did you get your sample program?

I can't find any reference to queryAsStream anywhere.

Comment: It's a old program which I inherited. Maybe this `queryAsStream` is a custom method?

Comment: Could be. Or the program could be assuming an ancient version of OJAI.

Comment: Any idea what code can be implemented?

Comment: I think that the examples here should work:

https://github.com/mapr-demos/ojai-2-examples/tree/master

Comment: I saw it. Can you give me some good example how to use them into my code, please?

Comment: Those are the examples of how to use them in your code. I can't make a concrete suggestion about your actual code because a) it's yours, not mine and b) the snippet that you show doesn't really explain what you are trying to do.